# typical android cpu split between app and kernel

Tags: android, kernel, cpu

What is the typical split between kernel CPU time and UserMode CPU time on an Android while executing a typical cpu-bound application ?

A typical dual core ARM android phone, while executing a common app, and not waiting for i.o from user or network

Even more helpful, if there is any data on the cpu time split between the usermode portion of system libraries, and time spent inside app actual code

(I realize this is a very subjective question, complicated by the jvm/jit and other functions but any pointers (ha!;) would be helpful.)

Comment: This is totally dependent on the actual task. If it's doing a lot of I/O, the kernel dominates; if it's doing a ton of arithmetic stuff (e.g. DSP calculations using NEON) then the user time dominates.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it really depends on the application. In an application that is I/O bound, the time will be spent in syscalls like `read` and `write`. In an application that is compute bound, the CPU time will be almost all userland. In an application that's RAM bound (doing a lot of manipulation of data in RAM) that CPU will spend most of it's time waiting for RAM because of cache misses (I don't think ARM processors have very large caches).

On the other hand, if your app does a lot of UI stuff, while all of the graphics processing is done in userland, there is still a lot of I/O bound operations waiting for the frame-buffer and input devices.